# Based on a 5 week period, how would I find the variance?

Tags: statistics

For the following problem, I'm not sure what to use to find the variance of each stock. Correct me if I am wrong, but can I use 1/5 for each week? Or should I use something else?

~

During a 5-week period in 2007, the stock of an insurance company and the stock of a small tech company showed the following weekly percentage changes. 
\begin{array}{|c|}
\
 & & &\\ \hline
InsuranceStock& .8&-1.7&-1.5&1.9&1.8\\ \hline
Tech Stock&  2.3&1.6&-3.9&-3.6&2.2\\ \hline
\end{array}

*Weekly Price Change (%)*

Find the variance of the weekly price changes of each.

**insurance stock**

**tech stock**

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that they're looking for the sample variances of the $n = 5$
weekly changes: For the insurance stock the $X_i,\, i = 1, 2, ..., 5$
are: .8, -1.7, -1.5, 1.9, 1.8.  So the sample mean is $\bar X = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = 0.26$
and the sample variance is $S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2 =3.073.$ In R statistical software, the computations are:

```
x = c(.8, -1.7, -1.5, 1.9, 1.8)
mean(x)
## 0.26
var(x)
## 3.073
```

In a homework assignment, you may be expected to show intermediate
computations. The sample mean and variance for the tech stock would be
found in the same way.

From a plot of the two stocks, it seems that the tech stock had the larger
variance over the 5-week period in question.

[image]